# Convert an array of Objects in individual objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I have the following example array of objects

```
[ 
{ key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
{ key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }
];
```

that I would like to only have individual objects like:

```
{ key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
{ key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }
```

and store them in useState like so

```
array.map((object)=>{
setObjects({...object})
 })
```

but when do

```
console log(objects)
```

it only outputs one object not all of them

Comment: you can't *store* individual objects like that in javascript, so you're on an uphill battle with syntax

Comment: What's the point of breaking up the array? How would you reference the individual objects anyway? This sounds very much like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ChrisG i would like to pass the objects in an api call

Comment: @louis Could you give an example of the API call input?

Comment: All of them? Or individual objects?

Comment: Full input of the one API call. Or do you want to call individual request for individual object?

Comment: Sending an individual object to an API can be done by rendering the array as a list and using the item's index to extract the object from the array. Again, you're trying to do something that is most likely not necessary at all.

Comment: @ChrisG I am sorry, ChrisG. I mistaken the users and believed that "All of them? Or individual objects?" was written by louis.

Comment: @Gynekolog No problem, you didn't @ me so I didn't even realize you were replying to me ;)

Comment: @Gynekolog  yeah I actually didn't need to extract the items from the array. Previously I was passing the  array directly  to the api and it brought errors, so I decided to extract the individual objects but i was told it isn't possible. I figured out i only needed to spread the array and the call goes through

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your object after each iteration. One way is to make a new object if you are sure the key will be unique then use this one.

```
array.map((object)=>{
 setObjects((prevState) => ({...prevState, [object.key]: object }) )
})
```

It will produce the output like this.

```
{
  11 : { key : '11', value : '1100', $$hashKey : '00X' },
  12 : { key : '22', value : '2200', $$hashKey : '018' }
}
```